# Laravel 5.7: Can I programmatically force Slack to not split longer message into two or more?

Tags: laravel, slack, slack-api

Funny case, I wrote a Slack Notification that is being sent each time cron job cleans some files.

One night the list of cleaned files was long enough that slack split that into two separate posts. There would be no issue except of the fact that I wrapped the content in a `pre` tags via:

````
public function toSlack()
{
    return (new SlackMessage)
        ->success()
        ->content(sprintf('*Garbage Collector*```%s```', $this->message));
}
````

By splitting a message the end result was that the first slack message had opening `pre` tag but didn't have a closing one, while the second one didn't have opening one and did have the closing one. Visual result was that both messages where not displayed in the plain text.

> Desired effect (occurs when the content is not too long):

[image]

> Behaviour I consider as a bug that I don't know how to fix (occurs
>   when the content is too long):

[image]

Second part:

[image]

Stub I use with `str_replace` below:

```
Garbage Collected

Environment:     {app_env}
Date:            {date}
{separator}

List of files deleted from the temporary directory:

{garbage}
{separator}
Reason:          {reason}
Space recovered: {garbage_size}

Have a nice day!
```

Can I somehow fix this within Laravel or is it up to boys from Slack?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of testing here is list of relevant limits for creating messages in Slack:

- Messages will be automatically split: > 4.000 chars in `text` (undocumented)
- Messages will be truncated: > 40.000 chars in `text` ([Source](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2018-04-truncating-really-long-messages))
- Attachment will be truncated: > 8.000 chars in `attachments` / `text` (undocumented)

As far as I know that behavior can not be changed and is the same for all the different ways to send a message:

- via Web API (chat.postMessage)
- via Incoming Webhook
- as response to a Slack request (slash / interactive message)

Here are a few ideas for a workaround:

1. Split the text in your app and send them as separate messages to Slack
2. Generate the text so that the cut at 4.000 will always be outside any formatting tags
3. Upload the whole text as text snippet with [`file.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload). Slack will then automatically show a preview of the text and the user can open the whole thing by clicking on it.

I would suggest 3. since its more user friendly.

Also see [this documentation](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/message_limits.md) for an overview of all known text limits in Slack messages.

Comment: This is a hint, I’ll try to make some adjustments and will let you know.

Comment: is there any way to achieve suggestion 3 with slack webhook? Thanks :)